# Нужна ли запятая перед "я" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Во время моей работы в качестве разработчика я периодически...

Answer (score 4):

Во время **моей** **работы** в качестве **разработчика** **я** периодически...

Запятая не нужна, обстоятельственный оборот со значением времени не обособляется.

Но предложение имеет стилистические погрешности.

Лучше сказать так: **Будучи разработчиком, я периодически...**   Или еще как-то изменить предложения, убрав повторы и однокоренные слова.

Answer (score 0):

[во вре́мя](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-synonyms3-term-2182.htm)
*предлог, с род. пад.* Употр. при выражении временны́х отношений, когда в один из моментов или на всем протяжении действия или состояния происходит что-либо; в процессе чего-либо, в ходе чего-либо.

1. Простое предложение — без союзов или союзных слов, без причастного или деепричастного оборота — запятая не требуется.
   (Возможно, Вы спутали предлог с союзом [В ТО ВРЕМЯ(,) КАК](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_127).)
2. Я бы убрала местоимение "моей" (мне оно кажется излишним) и подыскала подходящую замену слову "разработчик" (работа — разработчик): [см. синонимы](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-72613.htm).